# How to use Chrome content scripts to automate web page interaction and nested navigations

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to control chrome from my C# application.

I am looking to establish a fairly simplistic API between my C# application and Chrome.

```
- Navigate to url
- Find HTML element based on some criteria (typically to be done via jQuery)
- Click on the selected element
- Repeat as needed
```

My C# program will manage multiple Chrome instances doing this kind of work.

The solution that I am trying to implement is to use Chrome extension 'content' scripts

Here's my current Manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "ScraperAPI",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "content_scripts":  [
                {
                "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
                "js": [ "AutomationApi.js"],
                "run_at" : "document_start",
                "all_frames" : false
                }
    ],
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "storage" ]
    "web_accessible_resources": [ "jQuery.min.v.2.0.3.map" ]
}
```

The content script uses a WebSocket to communicate with my C# application

So far, the WebSocket works very well for communicating API requests (such as 'navigate') and responses (such as 'document ready').

My extension listens to document ready and opens up a WebSocket to my C# program.
    - This works

**My issues are:**

**[1] How to get the content script to launch automatically when Chrome comes up?**
    It appears that until I manually enter a URL at the navigateion bar, my extension is not loaded

How can the content script recognize that it is running for the first time in the chrome instance?

**[2] How to maintain general state for the content script across page loads.**

In particular, the C# program uses the content script to navigate to a URL,
    find a particular HTML element, click on it, and after 'document ready' it then
    wants to continue browsing and further clicking on the page.

Unfortunately (for me), each time a page is loaded, Chrome loads a new instance of the content script.

```
==> I don't know how to have the script determine whether it is running for the first time or not.
    On the first time through it has to open a WebSocket to the C#. On subsequent loads in the same tab
    I want it to recognize that the WebSocket connection exists and continue using it.

    I tried to create a 'window.myApi' object to save data, but each page seems to get a new window object.

    I was going to try to use 'local storage' but that is shared between all local instances of all the scripts
    and a fresh instance of the content script does not know whether it is running for first time or not.

    By the way, when my content script opens a WebSocket to the C#, the C# responds with a unique id (GUID) so
    all further communications use this unique id in the messages.

    It would be great if a content script can tell if it has been assigned a unique id by the C# program.

    Is there an 'uber' window for the entire Chrome instance that I can latch onto?
```

---

Should I be using a different approach (not using content scripts) to automate Chrome sessions?

Is there an approach to saving state that I missed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Many thanks in advance
[David]

Answer (score 0):

The execution environment of a content script is normally destroyed on navigation, so you can't have a permanent socket connection using only content scripts. A [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) is loaded when Chrome starts up, and will live until Chrome is closed. There you can have permanent socket connections, and store any state you need.

For any interaction with the HTML document, you still need to use content scripts. You can use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to relay messages between your C# application and the content scripts via your background page.

Comment: Makes sense. I should have realized this before posting the question.

Comment: I switched the app based on your advice. Many thanks. I noticed that the background page gets launched only after a URL has been entered in Chrome. It does not launch in an empty browser. How can I get it to launch as soon as Chrome runs even if there is no URL?

Comment: @davidmarcus the background page starts when chrome starts. It doesn't need to wait for any navigation event.